# Can anyone tell me the names of these Russian objects?

Tags: перевод, значения

https://ibb.co/mMSZG6

https://ibb.co/bKqApR

https://ibb.co/iXUgw6

What are the names of these? I assumed they were КолобоK and
собака to say of some.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it strongly appears to be outsourced visual captcha evasion. This is the kind of thing we ought to moderate instead of splitting hairs on what constitutes a "duplicate" or a "translation request".

Answer (score 1):

1. **Собака Жучка**
   [image]
2. **Колобок**
   [image]
3. **Дружинники**
   [image]

(Is this for a crossword?)

Comment: @Samzino Boss no prob.